# Getting 404 on Github Pages site with domain hosted by Namecheap (deanfriedland.com)

Tags: deployment, github-pages

First let me say thank you for providing me with help! I am a new dev and deploying and displaying my app has been a frustrating experience but I am determined to get it done. So I am trying to display an application located on my Github repository (located at https://github.com/dfmmalaw/portfolio-php). The domain name deanfriedland.com is hosted at Namecheap. I am trying to use Github Pages to display the site.

I followed the instructions for creating a CNAME  file and A records as well per Github's instructions. It displays fine on https://portfolio-php--dfmmalaw.c9.io/basic/web/index.php but when try load it from my domain it gives a 404 error. Can anyone please help me get it to display??

I tried contacting  Namecheap but they told me the following:

"Your site is redirected to dfmmalaw.github.io by CNAME record. Then, dfmmalaw.github.io is redirected to github.map.fastly.net by other CNAME. And that page show 404 error. All records are set properly in your DNS zone file. So it seems that there are issues on the GitHub side."

Answer (score 0):

You site is in a [project repository](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages), so, it must be in a `gh-pages` branch to be processed by Github pages.

But your php application will never work on github pages which is only serving static pages.